# Saving state and config data in bootable usb

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, bootable

My system hard disk has crashed, So now I want to run the OS(Linux mint or Ubuntu) from a bootable usb, but I don't know how to configure to save any config data so that it persist after rebooting also. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you install the system on your USB? Data will be persistent that way.

Comment: Be aware that you are running your system from a USB, USBs have a limited number of writes. To make the life of your USB longer put the directories where a lot of writes are done into memory so that the USB is not written that often.